# Python - If "\x" in string?

Tags: python, backslash

`if "\x" in string:` and `if "\\x" in string:` both do not seem to work correctly.

The following should return `True`:

```
string="It\x(randomcharshere) me!"
if "\\x" in string:
   return True
```

I cannot change the input string, as I've built a script to read data from a website automatically, and it sometimes returns \x and then some random characters when there's a special character in the fetched data, like an accent.

Comment: No it shouldn't because `\xa8s` is a unicode character sequence (`¿`). The original string does not actually contain `\x` in it.

Comment: `isinstance(string, unicode)` will tell you if `string` contains unicode.

Comment: @Selcuk So there's no possible way without hard coding all the possible not-sure-what-to-call-it's? I'm going to have to build a list of strings like "\xe2", and "\xa8" to test for?

Answer (score 4):

"\x" in a Python string is an escape character, what it does is that it tells the Python parser that the next two characters should be interpreted as hex and be replaced with the corresponding byte.

At execution time, the escape characters no longer exists anywhere in memory. At execution time, the string contains the escaped character instead of the escape sequence.

If you want to keep the escape sequence in memory, you need to escape the escape sequence, i.e. `string="It\\xa8s me!"`, or read the string from an external file that is not parsed by the Python parser.

Comment: I cannot change the input string, as I'm building a script to read data from a website automatically, and it sometimes returns \x and then some random characters.

Comment: @TrivisionZero How do you build a script?

Comment: @GaaraofDesert What do you mean?

Comment: @TrivisionZero You shouldn't search '\x' in string to detect that it contains accent. You should check "isinstance(string, unicode)" instead as it was mentioned above by mshsayem.

Comment: @TrivisionZero Try string.decode('ascii') and catch UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: @TrivisionZero: what are you really trying to do? Check for unprintable characters? Check for non-Latin characters? Check if the string isn't in German? Do you have a specific list of "safe" characters?

Comment: @LieRyan Pretty much identify anything that contains anything but the main characters on a keyboard to be removed. I'm using a site to get the data, and accents are sometimes included which is sent as '\x' followed by two different characters. I want to identify and remove these strings. I could keep a running list of the different codes, but every time a new one is encountered, I have to manually enter it.

Comment: @TrivisionZero: the site sends you the bytes corresponding to these characters, not \x. \x is just Python's way of displaying these bytes when you use repr() on a string. Rather than trying to remove unknown characters, you should try to fix your program so it understand them. Some readings: http://kunststube.net/encoding/ http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

```
string="It\xa8s me!"
```

Here **\xa8** stands for **¨**. So while searching **\x** in **string** it returns nothing.

Try this in python console.

```
>>> '\xa8'
'¨'
```